# Js - get string variable from env file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this value in my env file :

```
REACT_APP_CHAIN_ID=56
```

and when I try to get the value of this variable in my file test.ts :

```
console.log("address : " + process.env.REACT_APP_CHAIN_ID);
```

I have undefined value ?

Comment: They aren't available to React at runtime, only (probably) to your node server. The environment is a serverside concept. You'd have to handle that part. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Are you using CRA or your setup? [Here's how you'd do that with CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Comment: @dpwr is it a way to have this put this value in other file and to get it ?

Comment: Well, you could put it in a JSON (or something else, but more work) config file, then just import it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with using typescript instead. Rename all your **.js** files into **.ts**. And use `ts-node ./index.ts` instead.

But before that do not forget to install instances: `npm install -g typescript ts-node` or if you are using yarn: `yarn add -DE typescript` or just `yarn add -D typescript` then use `npx tsc -init` or simply `tsc -init`